# How do you infer the probability density function given a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a random variable that counts the number of heads when a fair coin is flipped n many times.

Given this fact, how can you know what PDF will map outcome of $X$ will be sent to a probability?

How do you know what form this PDF will take? Gaussian? Binomial?

My main question is what is the mapping between a random variable and its associated pdf?

Comment: I don't really understand your second sentence. The random variable you describe is discrete and does not have a pdf. In general the pdf of a random variable X is $d/dx P(X \le x)$ if the derivative exists.

Comment: So what would you do to derive a pdf? what are the steps taken?

Comment: Step 1: Find the cdf. Step 2: Take the derivative. Step 3: ????? Step 4: Profit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your set up (fair coin etc) let X = "Number of heads out of n". This is a random variable in that it can take any value from 0 to n. These values are not all equally likely and the probability of each value is your "pdf".
$P(X=k)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   n  \\
   k  \\
\end{matrix} \right){{p}^{k}}{{(1-p)}^{n-k}}$

where for a fair coin p = 0.5. This is the Binomial distribution and is arrived at by counting the possibilities - which you can look up. I put pdf in quotes because pdf refers to a continuous measure which has a density function (one that varies with a continuous variable rather than the discrete variable k).
The "cdf" in this example is the sum $P(X\le k)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}{P(X=j)}$.

Comment: Isn't that the pdf of the [_Binomial_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) distribution? I think it's a little confusing when you say `This is the Bernoulli distribution ...`.

Comment: @NauticalMile Apologies - in a hurry there! Edited.